# Systemd Path unit, check whether a file does NOT exist

Tags: systemd

I am trying to start a `systemd` service by detecting that a file does not exist. In the information about the `systemd.path` unit configuration, I find only the opposite, namely activation when a file exists (`PathExists=` in the `path` section).

I have tried to precede the file path by a `!` but with no luck. I guess it must be possible, but I have not been able to find the solution searching in Internet. Possibly I am using the wrong keywords in the search.

How can it be done? I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I want the service to be triggered as soon as the condition that the file does not exist is met, either from the very beginning when the path unit is enabled, if the file does not exist, or at any later time if the file is deleted by a process.

Comment: Did you spot `ConditionPathExists`, for use in the `unit` section?

Comment: I bet `PathChanged=` would be triggered when a file is deleted.  Perhaps monitoring the parent directory would also work.  You'll get false triggers, so you'd also have to detect if the file was actually deleted in your service.

Comment: Thanks, Kusalananda for the proposal. I think that this condition is not valid in the `unit` section of a path unit, only directly in the unit defining the service. I did not properly clarify it in the description of the problem (sorry, I will update it now!), but I want the service to be triggered as soon as the condition is met. If I add the condition that you propose in the service unit, to the best of my knowledge it will only be checked once and if the condition is not met, the service will simply not be executed, which is different from my desired behavior.

Comment: I had by the way Kusalanda spotted this option, this is why I hoped that the `!` would work with `PathExists=` as it does with `ConditionPathExists=`, but it doesn't. From a newbie perspective like me, I find it frustrating that the behaviour is not consistent across conditions. I am a little overwhelmed by systemd.

Comment: Thanks, Stewart. The problem with `PathChanged=` is, besides the one you point out, that, if the file does not exist in the first place at the time the path unit is activated, there will be no path change and the service will not be triggered.